# How to match plain text URL in a markdown?

Tags: regex, markdown

I'm currently trying to match all plain text links in a markdown text.

Example of the markdown text:

```
Dude, look at this url http://www.google.com .. it's a great search engine
```

I would like it to be converted into

```
Dude, look at this url <http://www.google.com> .. it's a great search engine
```

So in short, processing `url` should become `<url>`, but processing existing `<url>` shouldnt become `<<url>>`. Also, the link in the markdown can be in the form of `(url)`, so we'll have to avoid matching the normal brackets too.

So my working regex for matching the plain text url in java is :
`"[^(\\<|\\(](https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|][^(\\>|\\)]"`,

with `[^(\\<|\\(]` and `[^(\\>|\\)]` to avoid matching the wrapping brackets.

But here lies one problem where i also do **not** want to match this kind of url :

```
[1]: http://slashdot.org
```

So, if the markdown text is

```
Dude, look at this url http://www.google.com .. it's a great search engine
[1]: http://slashdot.org
```

I want only `http://www.google.com` to be matched, but not the `http://slashdot.org`.

I wonder what's the pattern to meet this criteria ?

Comment: In my own markdown parser I handle this kind of problem by parsing line after line and simply doesn't do replacements if some patterns (for example [1]:) are detected

Comment: what is your criteria between the two? number of dots? Or urls end wiht .org?

Comment: @oyss It's obviously when there's an integer between brackets before.

Comment: Do you really want to use regexp? I am not sure you can deal with code blocks + lists with them. Why not modify the parser?

Comment: When asking a question about regexes, don't forget to specify your language. It's terribly important here as some of them don't have negative look-behind for example...

Comment: @dystroy that is still too wild to write a pattern for it.I'm considering to use a negative look behind like (?<!...) to exclude that pattern.

Comment: @dystroy: Ah, my bad. I mentioned java in my question, but forgot to tag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a parsing problem. Regexes are fine, but just using regexes here will make it a mess (supposing you achieve it). After you fix this problem, you'll probably find yourself facing other ones, like URL in code (between ` or in lines starting with tabs or four spaces) that you don't want to replace.

A solution would be to split into lines and then

1. detect patterns (for example `^\[\d+\]:\s+`)
2. apply your replacements (for example this URL to link change) only on lines which doesn't follow an incompatible pattern

That's the logic I use in [this small pseudo-markdown parser](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/src/client-scripts/miaou.format.js) that you can test [here](http://dystroy.org/miaou/static/test_format.html).

Note that there's always the solution to use an existing proved markdown parser, there are many of them.

Comment: Yeah, i'm looking into it now. I'm currently using the txtmark parser. Thanks for the help !